# Overloaded increment operator that's supposed to only return a temp object changes the original object. Why?

Tags: c#, arrays, operator-overloading

I'm currently going through a C# course (a bit too outdated and terminology-heavy one to boot), and one of the demos is supposed to teach us how to overload operators in a class. They make an array class and overload unary operators - and ++. They're both written the same way, creating a temp new array object in which every integer is either inverted or incremented, and then return the temp. However, as revealed by printing the array, the - operation doesn't change the original array, while the ++ does. Why? The course doesn't explain anything in that regard and doesn't even tell what the desired output is. I don't even know if it's supposed to work this way or something has changed since the outdated time of this course's writing.

```
class DemoArray
    {
        int[] MyArray;
        public DemoArray(int size)
        {
            MyArray = new int[size];
        }
        public DemoArray(params int[] arr)
        {
            MyArray = new int[arr.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < MyArray.Length; i++) MyArray[i] = arr[i];
        }
        public int LengthArray
        {
            get { return MyArray.Length; }
        }
        public int this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                if (i < 0 || i >= MyArray.Length)
                    throw new Exception("out of array bounds");
                return MyArray[i];
            }
            set
            {
                if (i < 0 || i >= MyArray.Length)
                    throw new Exception("out of array bounds");
                else MyArray[i] = value;
            }
        }

        public static DemoArray operator -(DemoArray x)
        {
            DemoArray temp = new DemoArray(x.LengthArray);
            for (int i = 0; i < x.LengthArray; ++i)
                temp[i] = -x[i];
            return temp;
        }
        public static DemoArray operator ++(DemoArray x)
        {
            DemoArray temp = new DemoArray(x.LengthArray);
            for (int i = 0; i < x.LengthArray; ++i)
                temp[i] = x[i] + 1;
            return temp;
        }
        public void Print(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + ": ");
            for (int i = 0; i < MyArray.Length; i++)
                Console.Write(MyArray[i] + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
}
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                DemoArray Mas = new DemoArray(1, -4, 3, -5, 0);
                Mas.Print("Original array");
                Console.WriteLine("\nUnary inversion");
                DemoArray newMas = -Mas;
                Mas.Print("Array Mas");
                newMas.Print("Array newMas");
                Console.WriteLine("\nPrefix increment");
                DemoArray Mas1 = ++Mas;
                Mas.Print("Array Mas");
                Mas1.Print("Array Mas1=++Mas");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the output displays:

```
Original array:
1 -4 3 -5 0

Unary inversion
Array Mas:
1 -4 3 -5 0
Array newMas:
-1 4 -3 5 0

Prefix increment
Array Mas:
2 -3 4 -4 1
Array Mas1=++Mas:
2 -3 4 -4 1
```

So, why did the original array Mas get modified by the overloaded increment again? Btw, I've tried overloading the ++ operator **to inverse** integers and the - operator **to increment** them, and the - operator still doesn't change the original array, while the ++ operator does.

Comment: @rfmodulator Ouch, yeah, sorry, the original code has two constructors for DemoArray. One got lost in pasting apparently. Added right below the first line of its body, "int[] MyArray;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# automatically constructs increment, decrement, and compound assignment operators by calling the overloaded operator function and assigning the result.

You can read the rules in C# Language Specification [section 11.7.14 Postfix increment and decrement operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11714-postfix-increment-and-decrement-operators)

In particular, you get `+=` for free when defining `operator+`, and you get both prefix increment and postfix increment when defining `operator++`, and that works because C# controls when the assignment happens (so it can choose a different ordering for prefix and postfix).

There's even a note in [section 14.10.2 Unary operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#14102-unary-operators)

> Unlike in C++, this method should not modify the value of its operand directly as this would violate the standard semantics of the postfix increment operator.

(C++ requires the programmer to provide separate functions for prefix-increment and postfix-increment)

---

All of that said, your conclusion that `++Mas` changed the original array is incorrect.  The original array is still out there, unchanged (until the garbage collector finds it).  But the variable `Mas` is pointing to the new array, same as `Mas1` is.

Try this snippet for proof:

```
DemoArray Mas = new DemoArray(1, -4, 3, -5, 0);
DemoArray Old = Mas;
DemoArray Mas1 = ++Mas;
Mas.Print("Array Mas");
Mas1.Print("Array Mas1=++Mas");
Old.Print("Array Old");
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(Mas, Old)); // false
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(Mas, Mas1)); // true
```